# Writing to a data table with just foreign keys

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a PostGreSQL database with the following data model:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (s_id serial UNIQUE, name, username, password, email)
CREATE TABLE institution (i_id serial UNIQUE, name);
CREATE TABLE isStaffOf (i_id, s_id); //foreign key references
```

When a user submits the form I have a PHP script which writes the information to first two data tables and that automatically generates the s_id and i_id values. Great!

I've tried out a few PHP modifications to get the system writing both the s_id and i_id into the isStaffOf relation so it can enforce the explicit 1..1 relationship required for my project but on submit it says I have an insufficient data type. See below for the PHP code.

```
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $institution = $_POST["institution"];

    $conn = pg_connect("host=***** port=**** dbname=****** user=**** password=******");
    $staffWrite = pg_query("INSERT INTO staff(name, username, password, email) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$email')");
    $instiWrite = pg_query("INSERT INTO institution(name) VALUES ('$institution')");

    $instiFK=pg_query("SELECT i_id FROM institution WHERE name='$institution'");
    $staffFK=pg_query("SELECT s_id FROM staff WHERE name='$username'");

    $sql=("INSERT INTO isstaffof(i_id, s_id) VALUES ('$instiFK', '$staffFK')");
    $result = pg_query($sql);
```

That is the script I have at the moment but its not working. Any ideas on how to fix this so that when a user submits all the data tables will be filled and the referential integrity enforced? I'm almost there and still trying things out but to no avail.

The error message:

```
 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "Resource id #4" LINE 1: INSERT INTO isstaffof(i_id, s_id) VALUES ('Resource id #4', ...
```

Please let me know if you need more explanation but I'm sure its clear what I want to achieve and I'm convinced I can do it without so many `pg_query` calls.

Comment: Could you please do something against SQL injection? Never ever stick userinput without escaping into a query! Use pg_query_params() to simply use a prepared statement. It's very simple and a perfect solution against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL version 9.1, you can use a single query to INSERT in all 3 tables, a [writable common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
WITH 
step_1 AS(
    INSERT INTO staff (name) VALUES('Frank') RETURNING s_id
),
step_2 AS (
    INSERT INTO institution (name) VALUES('PostgreSQL') RETURNING i_id
)
INSERT INTO isStaffOf (i_id, s_id) SELECT i_id,s_id FROM step_1, step_2;
```

Simple, fast and reliable.

You could do some other tricks as well, when some records already exists and just want to select the primary key value.

Comment: worked perfectly! and I added some SQL Injection protection like you recommended. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fetch the result with [pg_fetch_assoc](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-assoc.php) or something similar. The way you're using it now you're passing the whole pg_query resource as an integer - obviously php can't convert that to a valid integer.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$institution = $_POST["institution"];

$conn = pg_connect("host=***** port=**** dbname=****** user=**** password=******");
$staffWrite = pg_query("INSERT INTO staff(name, username, password, email) VALUES ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$email')");
$instiWrite = pg_query("INSERT INTO institution(name) VALUES ('$institution')");

$instiFK=pg_query("SELECT i_id FROM institution WHERE name='$institution'");
$rowInsti = pg_fetch_assoc($instiFK);
$staffFK = pg_query("SELECT s_id FROM staff WHERE name='$username'");
$rowStaff = pg_fetch_assoc($staffFK);

$result = pg_query("INSERT INTO isstaffof(i_id, s_id) VALUES (".$rowInsti['i_id'].", ".$rowStaff['s_id'].")");
```

As an alternative you could probably use [pg_last_oid](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-oid.php) directly after every insert to get the id. (Even more beautiful would the RETURNING-solution be. Just read the comments on the php.net page)

Comment: thanks for the response, the PHP result doesn't like the `['i_id']` and `['s_id']` syntax. Its expecting a `T_VARIABLE or T_STRING` and not the `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` that is says are there currently

Comment: Try 

`$sql=pg_query("INSERT INTO isstaffof(i_id, s_id) VALUES (".$rowInti['i_id'].", ".$rowStaff['s_id'].")");`

Comment: Almost there `Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: INSERT INTO isstaffof(i_id, s_id) VALUES (22,)` that tells me the first value has been written but there's supposedly some syntax error? Was the ':' intentional? Because I changed it to a '.'

Comment: No, the : was a typo on my side ;)
By the way - As long as there is some syntax error in the query, it won't get written to the db no matter what.

The problem here is that the second id we put in our string seems to be empty, thus resulting in an invalid (22,).

(Also, there was another typo in my query above: it should be $rowInsti instead of $rowInti. And we're calling pg_query twice at the end - I fixed it in the code above)

Comment: I'm confused as to why its empty because the s_id is generated above in the code when I `INSERT` into the respective data table! Very confused!

Comment: Probably because there's something wrong with our query to retrieve it ;) Try to find out wether the query fails with http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php.

Answer (score 0):

WHEN creating the isstaffof table, you at least have to specify the datatypes, and you *can* specify they are foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE isstaffof
    (i_id BIGINT REFERENCES institution(i_id)
    , s_id BIGINT REFERENCES staff(s_id)
    );
```

NOTE: avoid using MixedCase for identifiers. It might cause terrible problems, if you ever have to port to a different DBMS platform.

UPDATE: Just put it in a plain `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE staff (s_id serial UNIQUE, sname varchar);
CREATE TABLE institution (i_id serial UNIQUE, iname varchar);
CREATE TABLE isstaffof
    (i_id BIGINT REFERENCES institution(i_id)
    , s_id BIGINT REFERENCES staff(s_id)
    );

INSERT INTO isstaffof(i_id,s_id)
SELECT i.i_id,s.s_id
FROM staff s, institution i
WHERE i.iname='$institution'
AND s.sname = '$staff'
        ;
```

Now, you can wrap that into your front-end code.

Comment: Hi there thanks for responding, I did specify the type I just left it out of the question for less to read, sorry!

Comment: I respect that and will do so in future. Luckily I implemented that table as you have done in your code anyway. Thanks for the input